# How to implement change.bfhselectbox event in Bootstrap Form Helper Select?

Tags: jquery, select, twitter-bootstrap-3, onchange

```
<div class="bfh-selectbox" data-name="item_id" data-value="0" data-filter="true">
                <div data-value="0" data-price="0" >None</div>
            <?php foreach($items->result() as $item){ ?>
                <div data-value="<?php echo $item->item_id; ?>" data-price="<?php echo $item->price; ?>" ><?php echo $item->company; ?> <?php echo $item->item_name; ?> <?php echo $item->caption; ?> <?php echo $item->size; ?></div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
```

Now I want to implemnt on change event where data-price attribute value should be auto populate in Price text box. Please help me

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" required id="price" name="price" value="1" min="1" placeholder="Price" >
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.bfh-selectbox').on('change.bfhselectbox', function () {
            var dataPrice = $(this).val();
       $('input#price').append(dataPrice);
   });

});
```

Make sure you have the jQuery library linked in your php file:

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ok I am getting the value of data-value

but now I want to get value of attribute data-price

please help me little more

Thanks